# Drag and Drop not working in Android Studio Design Tab

Tags: android, android-studio, drag-and-drop

I recently migrated from ADT to Android Studio. I am not able to get the drag and drop feature in the design tab to function properly. In the screenshot attached, I want to drag down the textView from the Palette but the textView will not move below that horizontal line that you can see. I never experienced something like this in ADT and I couldn't find a solution online.

[image: Android Studio design tab]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root `ViewGroup` is a vertically-oriented `LinearLayout`. By design, this `ViewGroup` arranges its children sequentially (in this case, top-to-bottom). You will need to use a different `ViewGroup` (e.g. a `RelativeLayout`) to accommodate the more flexible positioning you describe.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new project, you can choose Empty Activity template instead of Blank Activity. If you create a new activity, you can choose Empty Activity instead of Blank Activity too.

[Can't add any items to activity_main.xml in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129629/cant-add-any-items-to-activity-main-xml-in-android-studio)