# Can't add any items to activity_main.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, drag-and-drop

In Android Studio, I can't add any items from Palette to activity_main.xml in Design view. It just won't let me drag and drop them. Any idea why this happens?

Here is the PrintScreen:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to new design method followed in android studio for android development you cannot add any elements to the activity_main.xml. Rather you should add them to content_main.xml.

You can learn more about it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32880945/3975838) answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can stop it from happening.
**Answered by [BNK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4328123/bnk):**

> If you create a new project, you can choose Empty Activity template
>   instead of Blank Activity. If you create a new activity, you can
>   choose Empty Activity instead of Blank Activity too.

**how do I create an Empty Activity with a Fragment?**

> You start by creating an activity using the "Empty Activity" template.
>   Then, add a fragment class yourself or possibly via New > Fragment.
>   Please understand that all of the "New >" options, for activities,
>   fragments, etc., are all driven by templates. Those templates do what
>   they do. If you do not want what they are generating, don't use them,
>   and add the classes, resources, manifest entries, and such yourself.
>   Personally, I almost never use those templates, because it's simpler
>   IMHO just to create it all yourself than to rip out all the stuff you
>   don't need that gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In the design page, I saw error message "Render Error..."
I click Android Studio->check for update->update and restart
After android studio update, the drag&drop from Palette to design page works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check ConstraintLayout properties:
layout width and layout height should be "match parent", not "wrap content".
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

While you have marked a witget the editor don't let you drag.